# Success animation with timer - Sweet Alert on Ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, css, ionic-framework, bootstrapping, sweetalert

I am using ionic framework to create a mobile app.I want to use Sweet Alert  http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/ to show a success message.

I want to add a timer on

```
 swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success")
```

I see that there is a timer function, but it doesn't have that success check mark animation.

```
swal({   title: "Auto close alert!",   text: "I will close in 2 seconds.",   timer: 2000,   showConfirmButton: false });
```

Is there a way I can combine both of them together?

Answer (score 1):

Add `type:'success'` to your options to get the checkmark:

```
swal({   
  type: 'success',
  title: "Auto close alert!",   
  text: "I will close in 2 seconds.",   
  timer: 2000,   
  showConfirmButton: false 
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Very helpful. I am wondering other than Success and Error, are there any other types?

Comment: @UniSoundWaterloo the other types are documented on the page you linked to